# How can I link to a particular post when i click a tag in my Django app

Tags: python, django

On my detail page I have a list of tags in a column. The result I want is when I click a link in that column, it will take me to the post that corresponds to it.

Heres what I've tried so far

**post_detail.html**:

```
{% block content %}

<div class="row" style="margin-top: 70px">

    <div class="col-sm-8">
        {% if instance.image %}
            <img src='{{ instance.image.url }}' class="img-responsive" />
        {% endif %}


    <p>Share on:
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}">
    Facebook
    </a>

    <a href="https://twitter.com/home?status={{ instance.content | truncatechars:80 | urlify }}%20{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}">
     Twitter
    </a>


    <a href='https://plus.google.com/share?url={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}'></a>


    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}&title={{
    instance.title }}&summary={{ share_string }}&source={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}">
     Linkedin
    </a>
    </p>

        <h1>{{ title }}<small>{% if instance.draft %}<span style="color:red"> Draft</span>{% endif %} {{instance.publish}}</small></h1>


        {% if instance.user.get_full_name %}
        <p>By {{ instance.user.get_full_name }}</p>
        {% else %}
            <p>Author {{ instance.user }}</p>
        {% endif  %}

        <p><a href='{% url "posts:list" %}'>Back</a></p>
        <p><a href='{% url "posts:delete" instance.id %}'>delete</a></p>
        <p>{{instance.content | linebreaks }}</p>
        <hr>


    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the
        <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow">comments powered by Disqus.</a>
    </noscript>
    <script id="dsq-count-scr" src="//hispanic-heights.disqus.com/count.js" async></script>

    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default pull-right" style="height: 1000px">
        <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Similar Articles</h3>
      </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            {% for tag in instance.tags.all %}
            <h4> <a href="{% url 'posts:detail' slug=tag.slug %}"> {{ tag.title }}</a>  </h4><hr>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>


</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

This is the error I get

```
No Post matches the given query.
```

Ive also tried

```
tag.slug
tag.get_absolute_url
```

and a few other variations. but nothing works also, Heres my **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^$',   post_list, name='list'),
 url(r'^tag/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', tag_list, name="tag_list"),
 url(r'^create/$', post_create, name='create'),
 url(r'^sewp$', sewp, name='sewp'),
 url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
 url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', post_update, name='update'),
 url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/delete/$', post_delete, name='delete'),
]
```

Comment: Could you please add your model definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. You are mixing two things, named the same but representing different things:

- `Post.slug` which is a slug for a given post
- `Tag.slug` which is a slug for a given tag

You can't get to a post page from a tag's slug.

Comment: so how would I display all my tags associated with a post and then be able to click to them? what about backwards relations I've been researching this for the last few hours

Comment: You can link to the `tag_list` which would presumably display all Posts with a given tag. Replace `{% url 'posts:detail' slug=tag.slug %}` with `{% url 'tag_list' slug=tag.slug %}`.

Comment: No that odesn't work my error NoReverseMatch at /posts/but-if-you-look-in-m/. iIm willing to rewrite my code to make this work. I am new and don't know how it's typically done.

Comment: Where that error originates? Which line in the template?

Comment: it originates exactly where the code you gave me is

Comment: so if I wanted to do something like youtube where they have similar videos on the right hand side that are related to the current video. How would that be done with django?

Comment: Is that code here?        <div class="panel-body">
            {% for tag in instance.tags.all %}
            <h4> <a href="{% url 'tag_list' slug=tag.slug %}"> {{ tag.title }}</a>  </h4><hr>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102106/discussion-between-lukasz-and-losee).